# What does the @ mean in intellij variable view?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is a screenshot of what I see in my Intellij IDE

In this screenshot, what does the number that comes after @ represent? For example in the highlighted line - 13879

I'm guessing the memory location/address?

[image]

Comment: Read about the `Object.toString()` method. `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
 `

Comment: Intellij shows the result of `toString()`. If the Proxy class does not override it, it calls the `Object.toString()` method

Comment: probably the ID for that instance, a sequential number,  and not, as commented above, the result of `toString()` - it is definitively NOT the hash code - as we can see, the numbers are sequential in posted image (@Jens)

Comment: @user16320675 nice observation about the sequential numbers. Wish this was documented somewhere. ...

Comment: I do not use IDEA, but in Eclipse we have same behavior (I *suspect* that *ID* is related to the Java Debug Interface or similar)

Comment: @user16320675 and I see no documentation about this :( -https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inspecting_Variables.html

Comment: @user16320675 in what way sequential? if those are single digit numbers, they are not, since 8 shouldn't be before 7. If they aren't single digit numbers, there's no way of telling whether or not they are sequential or not, since there is no indication of what the separate numbers are

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry not exactly sequential but the fact that these numbers are so close together definitely rules out hashcode

Comment: @user16320675 thanks for the remark. I do remember something similar in Eclipse now

Comment: just did some test with JDI (Java Debug Interface) - the given ID most probably comes from [`ObjectReference.uniqueID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html#uniqueID()) - I did not check documentation or source code of IDEA (lunch time is restricted) but I get similar, almost same IDs as the debugger - these numbers are guaranteed to be unique for each instance, which is not the case of hash code! (Even if they are not sequential - they behave very much as if they were)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the id of your object if you want to improve it you can make a custom to string methode

Comment: They really should document this - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inspecting_Variables.html